# Hide markers on Leaflet -or- help filtering results from json url

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am using Leaflet to display upcoming open houses on a map from data I receive by fetching JSON from an URL.

The only value I have to work with is:
"ACTRIS_OpenHousePublicUpcoming":"Public: Sun Sep 5, 3:00PM-5:00PM"

I am able to convert this date to Sep 05 2021 using the following:

```
ophouse = ACTRIS_OpenHousePublicUpcoming;    
const [weekday,month,day,h1,h2] = ophouse.substr(8).split(/[\s,-]+/);
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getFullYear();
var openhousedate = [month,day, n].join(" ");
var formatted = openhousedate;
const javaScriptRelease = new Date(formatted);
const javaScriptRelease2 = new Date("2021/09/21");
```

From here I have tried to hide any marker that is in the past by hiding the `.leaflet-marker-icon` class.  I added the console log to make sure it was working and every result does come back with the correct log (ie. in the past or upcoming).

```
 if (javaScriptRelease2 < javaScriptRelease) {
    console.log('open house in the future');
} else {
    console.log('open house in the past');
    $(".leaflet-marker-icon").css("dislpay", "none");
    $(".leaflet-shadow-pane").css("dislpay", "none");   
}
```

For some reason this is not working. A lot of markers have been hidden if I use

```
$(".leaflet-marker-icon").css("opacity", "0");
```

but there are still expired open houses appearing in the results. Also when I zoom all results appear and none are hidden.

Is there a better way to achieve hiding these markers?

Here is a JsFiddle of my complete code... it is non-working because I have to hide the api token.  https://jsfiddle.net/planbjz/2aL0vbju/2/

Comment: Trying to hide Leaflet Markers through CSS may work in some cases, but sure is troublesome. Especially when the Markers are in a Leaflet.markercluster group, because the latter may not display them all at once (hence they "re-appear" when you zoom). What exactly are you trying to achieve? To not display some points which have a date older than a given one?

Comment: Hey...Yes, I'm just trying to hide expired open houses from showing up in the results.    They still appear in the json api even after they have gone expired.  As I mentioned the only thing I have to work with is the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do not create a Leaflet Marker at all when you have an expired data point:

```js
if (javaScriptRelease2 < javaScriptRelease) {
    console.log('open house in the future');
    // Create a corresponding Marker
    var marker = L.marker([element.Latitude, element.Longitude]).bindPopup('my content');
    markers.addLayer(marker);
} else {
    console.log('open house in the past');
    // Do nothing   
}
```